# What do "untracked directories" mean in Git?

Tags: git

From the [git clean](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) documentation, specifically the `-d` parameter:

> -d
>
> Remove untracked directories in addition to untracked files. If an untracked directory is managed by a different Git repository, it is not removed by default. Use -f option twice if you really want to remove such a directory.

What are "untracked directories"? Directories that don't have any tracked files in them? Because I don't think Git has a concept of tracking directories in the first place.

Are there other commands that work with this concept, or is it just `clean`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

True, Git does not track directories. "Untracked directories" are simply directories which contain only untracked (or no) files.

Answer (score 2):

That parameter is to recursively delete a complete untracked directory so a directory which contains only untracked files.